# how to remove substring of a column if it matches with string of another column using pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
          FULL_NAME   NAME
0        FIRST LAST  FIRST
1               NaN    NaN
2        FIRST LAST  NAME2
3       FIRST NAME3  NAME3
4  FIRST NAME4 LAST  NAME4
```

I'm trying to remove the substring of FULL_NAME if matches with the string of NAME. I tried something like this but unable to replace the substring with nothing:

```
df.FULL_NAME.replace({str(df['NAME']):''}, regex=True)
```

my desired output:

```
          FULL_NAME   NAME
0             LAST  FIRST
1               NaN    NaN
2        FIRST LAST  NAME2
3             FIRST  NAME3
4        FIRST LAST  NAME4
```

Comment: How would look your desired output? I can't see it clear

Comment: @Gamopo please check i have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
df['FULL_NAME'] =df.apply(lambda x: x['FULL_NAME'].replace(x['NAME'],''), axis=1)
```

This solution would let some unused spaces remaining, you can add `str.strip()` to make them disappear like this:

```
df['FULL_NAME'] =df.apply(lambda x: x['FULL_NAME'].replace(x['NAME'],''), axis=1).str.strip()
```